# Using PHP/YQL to scrape data from Yahoo's front page

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo, yql

I want to be notified if certain terms show up in Yahoo's top 10 "trending topics" list on their front page.  I created a little script that parses out the front page using file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com'); and then uses regex to parse it out. This works, but it's brittle. What if they change the html around a little bit?

I'd like to do this the right way and get this same information as XML. SO I looked into using YQL. I've found the right query:

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20timesense.trending%20where%20locale%3D'en-US'&diagnostics=true

But I don't quite understand how to use this to make my request because I get an Oauth error.

```
$request = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20timesense.trending%20where%20locale%3D'en-US'&diagnostics=true"; 
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$list = curl_exec($session);
echo $list;
```

gives me this error:

> Please provide valid credentials. OAuth
>   oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_PARAMETER_ABSENT_ERROR",
>   realm="yahooapis.com"Please provide valid credentials. OAuth
>   oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_PARAMETER_ABSENT_ERROR",
>   realm="yahooapis.com"

Now I know I need to create an access key/API key. I have one now. I just don't know how to include it. All the examples I see are either for social apps where I'd be requesting a user's login/password. All I want is to use PHP to get this one list of 10 things as XML. What can I do to get this? What should my next step be?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the YQL tables require "two legged" OAuth, basically meaning a signature on the request. My comments on this answer should help explain the signature steps needed:
[How do I get started with oauth for YQL for historical stock data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941569/how-do-i-get-started-with-oauth-for-yql-for-historical-stock-data/8947798#8947798)