# How do I make a Yahoo Weather API request that includes OAuth signing?

Tags: oauth, arduino, yahoo-weather-api

I'm using an Arduino UNO to connect to Yahoo Weather with the request

```
GET https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D55903793%20and%20u%3D%27c%27&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys HTTP/1.1
```

and I'm successfully retrieving the data. However, Yahoo mentions they are deprecating this kind of request, the **/public/** part must be removed and a Key and Secret must be used.

Can I make the request incorporating the Key and Secret directly into the above line as parameters? And if so, where do I put them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [making-yahoo-weather-api-request-with-oauth-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186538/making-yahoo-weather-api-request-with-oauth-1)

Comment: Checked that question before asking. Used @mattferderer Plunker to encode the url and it worked. What I want to know is if that can be accomplished without encoding, without that method, just by inserting the key/secret as parameters. If that encoded request is not permanent and process must be repeated, I'd have to implement or adapt OAuth libraries into the Arduino and resources are very limited.